# How to remove XML declation from the document while transforming the file

Tags: xml, dom

I am using DOM parser to parse my xml content.

After completing the parsing, I transformed the document to a new file. But it generates a new file that had added a new line for XML declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TFORMer major="1" minor="0">
<!-- (c) 1998-2008 TEC-IT Datenverarbeitung GmbH -->
```

In above line, the xml version declaration is automatically added by the transformer.

How do I configure the transformer to not to add that XML declaration line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line to your xslt file (processor), also method can be "html"

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>
```

Comment: there is alternative way also...transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");